# schaum's outline of differential geometry theorem 4.2

Tags: differential-geometry

This is related with schaum "outline of differential geometry" 
I want to prove the Theorem 4.2

If $x=x(t)$ is an arbitrary representation of a curve, 
\begin{align}
|\kappa| = \frac{|x' \times x''|}{|x'|^3}
\end{align}

---

Starting from the definitions related with curvature 
\begin{align}
&T = \frac{x'}{|x'|}\\
&\kappa = T'
\end{align}

Then 
\begin{align}
&T' = \frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{x'}{|x'|} \right)
= \frac{x'' |x'| - x' |x''|}{|x'|^2} \\
& |\kappa| = |T'|  = \frac{|x'' x' - x' x''|}{|x'|^2} 
\end{align}

Something definitely wrong in the computation!. Thm 4.2 states the denominator is $|x'|^3$!.

What is wrong with my computation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see, what is wrong. In the same textbook, problem 4.7 contains the proof of this theorem.  (I was wrong in the definition of T, and so on.) 
The right definition of $T = \frac{dx}{ds}$ where $s$ is a arc-length reparametrization which make its speed unit $|T|=1$. Thus 
\begin{align}
&x' =\frac{dx}{dt}  = \frac{dx}{ds} \frac{ds}{dt}  = T s' \\
& |x'| = s'
\end{align}

Using arc-length reparametrization

\begin{align}
&x' = \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{dx}{ds} \frac{ds}{dt} = \dot{x} s' \\
& x'' = \frac{d^2}{dt} x = \frac{d}{dt} \left(\dot{x} s' \right) 
= \dot{x} s'' + s' \frac{d \dot{x}}{dt} = \dot{x} s'' + (s')^2 \ddot{x}
\end{align}
where i used $\frac{d \dot{x}}{dt}  = \frac{d s}{dt} \frac{d \dot{x}}{ds}=s' \ddot{x}$
Then their cross product can be written as 
\begin{align}
x' \times x'' = (s')^3 (\dot{x} \times \ddot{x}) = |x'|^3  (\dot{x} \times \ddot{x})
\end{align}

Now recall the definition of curvature 
\begin{align}
|\kappa|=|\frac{dT}{ds}| = |\frac{d^2 x}{ds^2}|= |\ddot{x}|
\end{align}
Note that the norm of cross product 
\begin{align}
&|x' \times x''|=  |x'|^3  |\dot{x} \times \ddot{x}| 
= |x'|^3 |\dot{x}| |\ddot{x}| \sin(\dot{x} \cdot \ddot{x}) = |x'
|^3 |\kappa| \\
& \therefore \quad |\kappa| = \frac{|x' \times x''|}{|x'|^3}
\end{align}